# How can USB extension cords affect of USB charging?

Tags: usb, battery-charging

I want to use USB extension cords to extend the USB power cords for various devices (specifically, an iPad and Android phones).  When adding a USB extension cord to a closed system where the manufacturer power cord/adapter connect a device to a 120v outlet, how might charging behavior change and what are the effecting factors?  (The "charging behavior" I am most interested in is charging speed and long-term effects on the device battery.)

*Sidenote:
I thought this question might be too "end-user" for this site.  But I think it adheres to the [site guidelines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as it concerns "modifying [consumer] electronics for other uses" and the answer would concern their design.*

Comment: Can you define a "USB extension cord" for us? Length and wire gauge? This is necessary information and you shouldn't assume that my USB cables are the same as yours.

Comment: @smhmic  For future reference.  Plugging an off-the-shelf extension cable into an off-the-shelf charger doesn't constitute "*modifying electronics for other uses*".  Neither "*modifying*".  Nor "*other uses*".

Comment: @NickAlexeev your words make sense; I understand why this question is inappropriate for this site.  But out of all the SO sites, this one has the community with the most relevant expertise -- so I appreciate you giving your answer, anyway!

Comment: Extending USB cable length above spec value (3-5 meters) is forbidden by the spec. Such long cables are not guaranteed to work, even for charging purposes. See [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/19341/13327) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be a voltage drop across the cable.  Let's make a test case.

- length of extension cable: len = 2 m
- gauge of power wires in the cable: 24 AWG, which is typical for USB cables
- worst case charge current: I = 2 A, however this can vary a lot between various portable devices.  The range is between 0.5 A and 2.5 A.

24 AWG has [resistance](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) of 25.67 [Ω per 1000 feet] or 0.086 [Ω/m].  Both power and ground return leads need to be taken in account.  The total resistance is R = 2*2*0.086 = 0.342 Ω.  Voltage drop V = IR = 0.685 V per Ohm's law.

Nominally, the spec for the USB supply voltage is 5.00±0.25 V.  Lower supply voltage would probably not degrade your battery, but it may prevent your charger from working in the first place.  Try to get the extension cable with a heavier wire, if your charging current is high.

Answer (score 4):

All wire has a measurable resistance. The longer it gets, the more that resistance adds up, affecting the voltage and current at the other end of the wire. This is called voltage droop. If you do not calculate for that, you could end up with a significantly lower voltage at the far end. For USB, that's typically considered ±0.25V for a 500mA load. A lower voltage can cause a device not to charge or even recognize it is plugged in.

And depending on the cable used, not all pins could be wired, so some devices will not be able to detect what kind of charger they are using.

Other than that, there are too many variations on cables and devices, host or peripheral, to accurately tell you what will happen.